# parsing const char * returns a little up looking triangle. which character is it?

Tags: c, parsing, utf-8, character-encoding

Hi I am writing a function that prases one by one the elements of a const char * variable and

then I write every one of the characters in a txt file. It recognizes all of them

but I have some questions. when it changes line and does not show the character recognized this means that the character is '\n'???

and last character in the cons char * variable it shows me a little triangle, looking up.
It is without colour, only 3 lines forming a little triangle. I am using UTF-8 encoding.

The triangle which character it represents?? 
any advice welcome

Comment: How are you looking at the `const char*` variable to determine that it contains a little triangle? In a debugger or something?

Comment: Could we see the little triangle, please?

Comment: I am loooking the cons char * in a for loop examining every element.

Comment: searching I saw that this litlle up looking white triangle corresponds to ut8 encoding with code U+25B5 in unicode and 0x25b5 in utf8.

Comment: Alright, and in the loop body, do you print each char (for example, by calling `putchar`)? Some code (and its output on your system) would even be better.

Comment: the code i use to parse const char * is  for(int j=0;j<(strlen(outWrite)+1);j++)
        {
            myfile << j << "element in order is << outWrite[j];
        }
        myfile << "\n\n\n";

Comment: it just takes every outWrite[i] and sends it in the txt file.

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25b5/index.htm to see the triangle

Comment: You are also writing the null character to the file...

Comment: You can also use `od -t x1 filename` to dump the characters in the file.

Comment: Please show us the triangle by copy-and-pasting it into your question.

Comment: [UnicodeData.txt](http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt) has 76 occurrences of "TRIANGLE", and 5 occurrences of "UP-POINTING TRIANGLE".

Comment: 25B5;WHITE UP-POINTING SMALL TRIANGLE;So;0;ON;;;;;N;WHITE UP POINTING SMALL TRIANGLE;;;; i think it is this triangle. I checked the function that creates the char* result and probably the triangle is '\0' which means end of string. Also before this there are 2 '\n'.

Comment: `0x25b5` is not a UTF-8 encoded character.  The Unicode codepoint `U+25B5` is encoded in UTF-8 as `0xE2 0x96 0xB5` instead ([the page you linked to](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25b5/index.htm) even says so). There is no way you can loop through a UTF-8 encoded `char` string one `char` at a time and see the triangle, as it takes 3 `char` values working together to produce the triangle.

Comment: @ararar: If you copy-and-paste the triangle character into your question, or even into a comment, we can tell you exactly what character it is. There's no reasonable way that `'\0'` would be displayed as a triangle.

Comment: @KeithThompson: It would be reasonable if the text editor being used to display the text visually is using symbols to display non-printable characters, like null characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I am not sure I understand where the little triangle is from. But this seems irrelevant.) This link **will make you happy**: To lookup unknown Unicode glyphs by shape, see [shapecatcher.com](http://shapecatcher.com/). Just draw the character, and shapecatcher looks up glyphs that look similar.

Internally uses enslaved ape brains.

---

**EDIT: Based on your comments,** you are actually outputting a '\0' character to the file. How this gets displayed as small triangle is not clear - maybe you are looking at the file via an editor that displays '\0' this way.

Comment: In my parsing loop is outWrite[j]=='\u25B5' enough to recognize it?

Comment: Assuming you use `char *outWrite` and your system was built on this planet, each element of outWrite will only contain one byte, that is, the little triangle will actually occupy two chars. Your compiler should complain. To process unicode, you want `wchar` (or something similar), not `char`.

Comment: I did some tests, it recognizes the triangle as a '\0' and as NULL.

Comment: what does it mean,is it a '\0'? it means end of the string right?

Comment: Well, C strings are usually terminated by a trailing '\0' char. I cannot imagine how this is displayed as a little triangle. You did not elaborate on this, so **where do you see a triangle?**

Comment: I see the triangle at the end or every outWrite char *. Outwrite has length=5. So when I send outWrite[5] to my txt file, there it shows up as the little triagnle. outWrite[5] when I check if(outWrite[5]=='\0') returns true. it returns true if also I check if(outWrite[5]==NULL) which probably is wrong because my compiler gives me a warning

Comment: @tiwo: C strings are terminated by a trailing `'\0'` character; no need for the "usually". That's how the word "string" is defined in C.

Comment: @ararar: `NULL` is a null *pointer* constant.  `'\0'` is a null *character* constant. They're not interchangeable.

Comment: Writing a `'\0'` to a file writes a null character, not a triangle character. The **application** that you are using to **view** the contents of the file is what is displaying a null character as a triangle, that's all. The triangle is not in the actual file data itself.

Comment: @KeithThompson: depending on the compiler, `NULL` may just be a define for `0`, which does make it interchangable with `'\0'`, though you should not rely on that. `NULL` is deprecated in C++11 with the introduction of `nullptr` to eliminate that ambiquity.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Agreed -- but they're not interchangeable in the sense that code that uses `NULL` as a null character constant is non-portable and ugly. BTW, `NULL` is not deprecated in C, not even C11 (C doesn't have `nullptr`).

Answer (score 1):

You could 'od -x' the resulting file to see the hex representation of the character.